# Every HTTP client other than $http is giving me "Hello, world!"

Tags: angularjs, http, browserify

I am working on a project that requires me to POST to a remote server and get the streamed response put onto a dialog. Everything's working, except for the fact that `$http` is tacking a random character to the beginning of each response. To fix this, I am trying to use a different HTTP client. I have tried using Browserify's `http` module, `request-promise`, and jQuery, but all of them just return `Hello, world!` as the response.

Relevant HTTP request code with jQuery:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  $.post('http://signumd-5b4087ed.lambdavps.svc.tutum.io:3000/run/java', {environment: environment, code: $scope.code})
  .done(function (data) {
    resolve(data)
  }).fail(function (err) {
    reject(err)
  })
}).then(function (output) {
  console.log(output)
  return $mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'ResultDialogController',
    templateUrl: 'partials/result-dialog.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    locals: {
      output: output,
      expected: $scope.problem.contents.cases[0].stdout
    }
  })
}).then(function (answer) {
  window.alert(answer)
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Relevant HTTP request code with Angular:

```
return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://signumd-5b4087ed.lambdavps.svc.tutum.io:3000/run/java',
  data: {
    environment: environment,
    code: $scope.code
  }
}).then(function (output) {
  return $mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'ResultDialogController',
    templateUrl: 'partials/result-dialog.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    locals: {
      output: output.data,
      expected: $scope.problem.contents.cases[0].stdout
    }
  })
}).then(function (answer) {
  alert(answer)
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Branch I'm working on this in: https://github.com/ID10T-Errors/signum-workshop-client/tree/t%CD%8A%CD%94h%CD%92%CC%A2e%CC%9D%CD%86y%CC%B2%CC%8F-%CD%98%CC%A3%C5%88%CD%95e%CD%9D%CC%A6e%CC%9E%CC%8Bd%CC%83%CD%96-%CC%A2%CD%8Ct%CD%8E%CC%81o%CC%A7%CD%8B-%CC%B0%CC%8Ad%CC%AF%CC%BF%C3%AC%CD%95e%CC%9D%CC%88

Branch that semi-works (except for the extraneous characters): https://github.com/ID10T-Errors/signum-workshop-client/tree/gh-pages

Online working version: http://workshop.ctftoolkit.com/

Comment: The code, and all the other relevant information, must be in the question itself. Not hidden behind links that will be obsolete tomorrow.

Comment: I have no idea what the backend is expected, what you're sending, and what you're receiving, but the jQuery code posts the data as a query string (as [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), whereas $http sends it as JSON. If you want to post as jQuery, use `params` instead of `data`, and use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Answer (score 0):

I AM AN IDIOT

The server had defaults that produced "Hello, world!" when there was no input, which happened because I had no `Content-Type` header.